# what is the appropriate answer to this clause?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, american-english, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

[image]

I got this question, but I'm very confused between A and D.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer should be d) come to terms.
In English, the phrase "come to terms" is synonymous with "accept" or "recognize to be true". The other answer choices would not make any sense. For example, "bring it on" is a phrase usually used to challenge someone in a fight.